# Debug only paradigm in Lua?

Tags: c#, c++, build, lua, xdebug

In C/C++ we've had

```c
#ifdef _DEBUG 

    ... 

#endif
```

In C# we've got

```cs
#if DEBUG 

    ... 

#endif
```

and

```cs
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
```

I don't expect anything as fancy as an attribute based way of dealing with debug only code but would like to know if there's a manifest constant kind of thing or any other way of making code only present in a debug build.  For instance I'm doing the following in Lua at the moment:

```lua
if not type(parameters.callback) == 'function' then

    error('The "callback" parameter is not a function, or missing (nil).');

end

if not type(parameters.times) == 'number' then

    error('The "times" parameter is not a number or missing (nil).');

end

if not type(parameters.interval) == 'number' or not parameters.interval == nil then

    error('The "interval" parameter is not a number.');

end
```

> I don't even know if that will run.  Totally new to the language.

Given the nature of the function I'm writing, a simple `retry` function taking the number of attempts to make, an optional interval and a callback as parameters - which I anticipate being used many times throughout the application being written - and that its to be run on a micro controller I feel these checks should not be made in a production release as I'm guessing they could be relatively costly?!?!   I'm even doing a type check within a for loop.

Is there already something built into the language to allow for conditional compilation?  Or has anyone come up with a neat and clean way of handling this sort of thing?  I know I could declare a global variable marking it a debug build and simply put and if block around the above but I thought I'd ask.

Googling has got me nowhere.  In fact when I read the sites that talk about Lua I feel like I've stepped back to the mid to late 90's web.

Thanks,
Lee.

**EDIT**

Or perhaps I just write the method as a C module?!?!

Comment: I don't think your code will be "costly" though. Lua is pretty fast.

Comment: The cost concern comes from the fact it will be used on a micro controller but the particular ones being used are pretty nippy.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> way of making code only present in a debug build

There is no "build" for Lua. It's an interpreted language. Internally it is compiled to byte code, but that's an implementation detail.

However, if you're OK with having a build step, then you can just use a precompiler, exactly as C does. In fact, you can use the same one your your C compiler does, then you're getting the exactly syntax you're already familiar with.

For instance, my old copy of MSVC uses `cl /EP <filename>` to run `filename` through the preprocessor and dump the output to stdout. Then you can write:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG 

    -- debug Lua code goes here

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would probably be something like

```
_DEBUG = true

if _DEBUG then
    --code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The flavour of Lua being used is eLua or Embedded Lua and it does allow pre-compiling scripts to bytecode.

The code is on GitHub so if time permits I'll see about submitting a patch that will allow for true conditional compilation as it's all C under the hood.

In that way everyone benefits.  Whether the checks in the original question are costly or not there are often times when you want code in or out depending upon whether you're actively working on it or its being used in a production environment but not the other way around.

And since they support pre-compilation and only target embedded devices with differing levels of performance and memory constraints I wouldn't be surprised if they haven't already implemented support.  I'll hop along there and find out next.

Thanks all.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you most

Comment: I believe mine did. I offered all suggestions and proposed an additional solution.